# Are there no positive solutions for $ a^3 + b^3 = c^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history

Fermat's last theorem has no positive solution, for functions of the form of $a^n + b^n = c^n$, where $n > 2$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But I have heard that Fermat wrote in his diary that solutions exist for $a^3 + b^3 = c^3$. Is the thing written in the Diary actually by Fermat, or a rumor spread about.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem

Comment: I checked in the internet, I am asking about the diary factor. Are there any reliable sources with evidence

Comment: Your sentence "there are solution exists for $a^3+b^3=c^3$ which he said there is no solution exists" is unclear. Please rephrase.

Comment: I have updated the question @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Wikipedia (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dernier_th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Fermat#cite_note-4):

"Cubum autem in duos cubos, aut quadratoquadratum in duos quadratoquadratos, et generaliter nullam in infinitum ultra quadratum potestatem in duos ejusdem nominis fas est dividere : cujus rei demonstrationem mirabilem sane detexi. Hanc marginis exiguitas non caperet."

which is rendered as

"It is impossible to separate a cube into two cubes, or a fourth power into two fourth powers, or in general, any power higher than the second, into two like powers. I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain."

Comment: Euler published proofs that the equations $x^3+y^3=z^3$ and $x^5+y^5=z^5$ have no solutions in positive integers. A 19th-century mathematician had a form-letter for replies to amateurs' attempts to prove Fermat's Last Theorem: "Your attempted proof of FLT has a mistake on Page __ , on Line __ ."